# Why Java Objects producing different outputs in Java Inheritance?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

```
class Book {
    int op,mp;
    String name,auther;
    void Setdata(String n,String au)
    {
        name=n;
        auther=au;

    }
    void Display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name:"+name);
        System.out.println("Auther:"+auther);
        System.out.println("Ocford price: "+op);
        System.out.println("MC price: "+mp);
    }

}
class Oxford extends Book
{
    void price(int p)
    {
        super.op=p;
    }
}
class Mc extends Book
{
    void price(int p)
    {
        super.mp=p;
    }
}
public class Sai
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Oxford o=new Oxford();
        Mc m=new Mc();
        Book b=new Book();
        b.Setdata("Java","Robert");
        o.price(300);
        m.price(400);
        b.Display();
    }
}
```

**My output:**

- Name: Java
- Auther: Robert
- Oxford price: 0
- Mc price: 0

**Expected ouptut:**

- Name: Java
- Auther: Robert
- oxford price: 300
- mc price: 400

Why the objects of the two classes
(Oxford,Mc which extends by book class)
cannot assign values to book's class variables.
What is the solution to print the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are printing out the fields in object `b`, which is of type `Book`. The other objects are just sitting there with their fields initialized, waiting for you to do something with them.

You want to call:

```
o.Display();
m.Display();
```

`super.op` does not do what you expect it to do. Your fields are not `static`, so changing the value in one instance has no effect on other instances. Each of your three objects has an *independent* value of `op`.

Comment: To make the answer perfect a) tell the OP to use fields like that is really bad practice and that b) he should follow Java naming conventions, like having method names in camelCase.

Comment: @Ghost I didn't want to antagonize the OP.

Comment: You always write answers also for all future readers. And telling a newbie about all problems in his code, how could that be a bad thing?

Comment: Wrong answer. I think you did not get this question.check my last part of answer. Please mention if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Its not how object and inheritance work.

You need to learn static variable and non static variable.

**Static variable :-**

> It's class level variable and accessable to all object of same or
>   inherited class.

**Non-Static variable :-**

> It's scope is object level. Means every object have their own copy of
>   variable. Like if there is a variable int a = 10; then every object
>   have 1 copy of a. If you change value of a in 1 object, It will not
>   change value for another object.

Now coming to your code You have made some mistake. compair your code with below code. also I will comment on every line, I will change.

```
class Book {
    int op,mp;
    String name,auther;
    void Setdata(String n,String au)
    {
        name=n;
        auther=au;

    }
    void Display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name:"+name);
        System.out.println("Auther:"+auther);
        System.out.println("Ocford price: "+op);
        System.out.println("MC price: "+mp);
    }

}
class Oxford extends Book
{
    void price(int p)
    {
        super.op=p;
    }
}
class Mc extends Oxford  // If you want to set all price for same book and aurthor
{
    void price(int p)
    {
        super.mp=p;
    }
}
public class Sai
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        Book b=new Mc(); // also you can define it as Mc b=new Mc(); but its advised to define object as generalize as possible.(another whole topic )

        b.Setdata("Java","Robert");
        b.price(300);
        b.price(400);
        b.Display();
    }
}
```

It will give you desired output.

Comment: The task is to use Hierarchical inheritance where the two classes extends the same Book class.

Answer (score 0):

`Oxford o=new Oxford(); //implicitly create one book object
 Mc m=new Mc(); //implicitly create anoter book object
 Book b=new Book(); //explicitly creating book object`

if you look closely you will see there are 3 Book objects(1 you explicitly created, rest of 2 are automatically created as per inheritance) present in memory 
so setting

```
o.price(300); //setting the property of first implicit book object 
m.price(400); // setting the property of second implicit book object
```

will not affect the explicit object you have created.

So to get the desired result you better use composition rather than the inheritance.
Frankly speaking, this is not an ideal problem to use inheritance here to get desired output you can simply use a single class

```
    class Book {
    int op,mp;
    String name,auther;
    void Setdata(String n,String au)
    {
        name=n;
        auther=au;

    }
    void Display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name:"+name);
        System.out.println("Auther:"+auther);
        System.out.println("Ocford price: "+op);
        System.out.println("MC price: "+mp);
    }

    void setMp(int p)
    {
        mp=p;
    }

    void setOp(int p)
    {
        op=p;
    }

   }

   public class Sai
   {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        Book b=new Book();

        b.Setdata("Java","Robert");
        b.setOp(300);
        b.setMp(400);
        b.Display();
    }
   }
```

Comment: The task is to use Hierarchical inheritance where the two classes extends the same Book class

Comment: then could you please state the problem statement ? is it possible to use only one class price rather than different price classes.